# Add Loading Icon before the submit button When Button is Disabled

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

In my Detail Form there's on Submit Button
on click I'm calling a Ajax request 
[image]

while ajax request is processing my submit button is disabled 
[image]

What I want is to show loader icon like `fa-spinner fa-spin` when button is disabled 
[image]

here's a challenge

1. I don't want to add any tag inside a button `<button disabled>...</button>`
2. using only HTML, CSS, font-awesome

I'm also trying to develop this, but I think I can get more good suggestion here.

[Here JsFiddle for basic start](https://jsfiddle.net/RaviMakwana/6q2jghLy/11/)

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

button:disabled{
  opacity: 0.66
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Show loader on button Disabled</p>
  <button type="button" id="btnSubmit"> Submit</button> <!-- should not change anything inside button tag, you can add class or property -->
  <br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="this.checked? $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled','disabled'): $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled')" /> Disable Button</label>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code from the fiddle directly in your question. External links are discouraged because they can break or change over time and your question is no longer useful to the community. See how to create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in that case you could use a pseudo element like before, and add the css of the fa spinner to it :D

```
button:before {
  content: "\f110";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: .1em .4em .2em 0;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 900;
  animation: fa-spin 2s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}

button:disabled:before {
  opacity: 1;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your jsFiddle, you could add the following

```
.fa-spinner {
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

button:disabled .fa-spinner {
  width: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

If this is what your were looking for.

Comment: Good one but still i need to add <i class="fa-spinner".... 

https://jsfiddle.net/RaviMakwana/6q2jghLy/21/

Answer (score 1):

I write a full example for your situation.

```js
    function submitForm() {

        $('.form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var form = $(this);
            var submitButton = $('.js-submit-btn');

            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                beforeSend: function () {

                    // it's action will launch after you click submit button on form

                    submitButton.attr('disabled', true);

                    if($(submitButton).has('.fa-spinner').length === 0) {
                        $(submitButton).prepend('<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
                    }

                },
                complete: function () {

                    // it's action will launch after ajax request end

                    setTimeout(function () {

                        submitButton.attr('disabled', false);

                        if($(submitButton).has('.fa-spinner').length) {
                            $(submitButton).find('.fa-spinner').remove();
                        }

                    }, 1500);

                },
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('Response: ', response);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });

    }

    submitForm();
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/your_action_url" class="form" >

    <input type="text" name="client_name" placeholder="Your name">

    <input type="email" name="client_email" placeholder="Your email">

    <button type="submit" class="js-submit-btn"> <i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Send Email</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

to show a loader on particular button just need to add class `disabled-on-loading`

example `<button class="disabled-on-loading" />`

```
.disabled-on-loading:disabled:before {
        opacity: 0.65;
        content: "\f110";
        font-weight: 900;
        display: inline-block;
        font: normal normal normal 14px/1;
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        display: inline-block;
        text-rendering: auto;
        line-height: 1;
        animation: fa-spin 1s infinite steps(9);
    }
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

button:disabled{
  opacity: 0.65
}

 .disabled-on-loading:disabled:before {
        opacity: 0.65;
        content: "\f110";
        font-weight: 900;
        display: inline-block;
        font: normal normal normal 14px/1;
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        display: inline-block;
        text-rendering: auto;
        line-height: 1;
        animation: fa-spin 1s infinite steps(9);
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Show loader on button Disabled</p>
  <button type="button" class="disabled-on-loading" id="btnSubmit"> Submit</button> <!-- should not change anything inside button tag, you can add class or property -->
  <br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="this.checked? $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled','disabled'): $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled')" /> Disable Button</label>
  
</div>
```